Why AndroidX source code is available outside of AOSP?
Can you let me know Why AndroidX source code is available outside of AOSP. Why it has been maintained separate source code from AOSP?
What happen if we deploy AndroidX source code into AOSP?
Can someone explain the reason of maintaining it as separate source code from AOSP?
AOSP source code: https://cs.android.com/android
AndroidX source code: https://cs.android.com/androidx
I have a thought process of creating a folder called as android into AOSP path: frameworks/base/core/java/androidx
Let me know whether you tried and how long is it feasible to proceed?

A short from a quick Google of androidx vs aosp gives: AndroidX and the Android Open Source Project (AOSP) are both related to Android, but they have different purposes and features, so it sounds intentional or it would already be combined.

~99.9999% of the world's source code lies outside of the AOSP. Why would the Jetpack libraries be inside the AOSP?

@CommonsWare Because I want to modify the source code of AndroidX. If it is part of AOSP, then I don't want to build AndroidX separately and integrate the library in the application. If it is part of AOSP, I can modify AndroidX(eg: AppcompatActivity source code), and run the build of System apps.

@Star why would it matter if its in ASOP or not, neither are related to each other

@tyczj Because I want menus to display at bottom of the navigation bar of System UI.(instead of recent.)  I modified in ActionMenuPresenter of AOSP to display menus at the bottom for an application that extends Activity.  But When an application extends AppcompatActivity, it goes to ActionMenuPresenter of AndroidX, thus hamburger menu is displaying at top of the action bar, hence I need to modify to bring the menu at bottom, build and integrate this library into every application. If it is inside AOSP, it directly depends on AOSP platform.

app will be using "own" internal AndroidX import, won't be using yours modified one even if built-into system afaik...

Then how come Activity is using AOSP? Because Activity code is available inside AOSP source code. @snachmsm

@Star I think you have a misunderstanding of how Jetpack libraries work Jetpack libraries are optional libraries that an app can implement. They leverage core ASOP classes and build ontop of them. If you were to make a change to a Jetpack library the only apps that would see that change are apps that implement that specific version of it. If an app used the normal google version they would not see your changes

Because its not possible to make it part of AOSP.  It's an external library built on top of Android that is used to smooth over differences between versions of Android.  So if the parameters to a function X change between versions of Android, the support library (androidx) will provide a consistent interface across all those versions and you don't have to worry about it.  Given this, it can't be part of AOSP, as it needs to change over time with new versions of Android.

AndroidX is just a name of library, days ago renamed from Support Library. This is not part of the system, rather a tool which helps developer writing code working on variety of OS versions

You mean AndroidX libraries are not built into the Android operating system itself (AOSP)? They are external libraries that developers can include in their apps in the gradle. @snachmsm

exactly, this is not part of system, rather helper for supporting variety of system versions (consecutive) used by apps devs
